# IntelliJ IDEA target directory not visible any more maven

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

Maybe someone know the answer.
I made unchecked exclude build directory in settings and don't have any excluded files in settings. [modulesettings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nof1F.png)

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-193.6015.39, built on January 21, 2020
Runtime version: 11.0.5+10-b520.30 x86_64

Do you know how make target directory visible with this options?

Comment: Do you mean that "target" folder isn't shown in Project Tree view? Could you please attach screenshot with current Project Tree state?

Comment: Here it is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m8uX8kexy67Ox1vDEUE2WbyXfK9t5MGv/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Is it reproducible with every project? Is it added to .gitignore file?